# What are the advantages / disadvantages of the ANTICOR algorithm?

Tags: correlation, portfolio-selection

The algorithm is introduced in the paper, *[Can We Learn to Beat the Best Stock](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/JAIR/Vol21/JAIR-2117.pdf)*.

The obvious advantage is superior risk-adjusted returns (if you can actually achieve them).  Transaction costs and sensitivity to window size seem to be potential disadvantages.

I'm hoping someone can provide more insightful advantages / disadvantages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the major assumptions is that you have zero transaction costs. Another one is that your returns are tax-free. Otherwise it looks to me to be a windowed version of CBAL (constant rebalanced).

A more technical analysis can be found at:
Castonguay, [Portfolio Management: An empirical study of the Anticor algorithm](http://digitool.library.mcgill.ca/webclient/StreamGate?folder_id=0&dvs=1303954512559~100) (An MS thesis)

Covan and Gluss, [Empirical Bayes Stock Market Portfolios](http://www.stanford.edu/~cover/papers/paper67.pdf) (CBAL)